# Show product meta in order items table in Order Details

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to add custom column for order items and show specific product meta in this column.
I mean something like image below,
I can't find any action from woocommerce to add this column!
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
// Add custom column headers here
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers');
function my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers() {
    // set the column name
    $column_name = 'Test Column';

    // display the column name
    echo '<th>' . $column_name . '</th>';
}

// Add custom column values here
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 10, 3);
function my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values($_product, $item, $item_id = null) {
    // get the post meta value from the associated product
    $value = get_post_meta($_product->post->ID, '_custom_field_name', 1);

    // display the value
    echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
}
```

I've commented it so it should be clear enough, but in a nutshell this code adds a custom column, named "Test Column", and this column pulls the value from the custom field of the product, called "_custom_field_name".

Comment: Thanks,Thanks,Thanks..., you save me a lot of times! thanks again :D

Comment: The only problem with this code is that it pulls in the current meta value of the product ... rather than the meta value that was (potentially) captured during checkout.

Comment: @Marin Atanasov if i need to edit the custom meta value from the order line item, how can i do that?

Comment: Is there a way to also remove the default woocommerce columns, Cost, qty, total, tax?

Answer (score 2):

Since WooCommerce 3.0 you are not allowed to call the product_id directly. You need to replace this:

```
$product_id = $_product->get_id();
$value = get_post_meta($product_id, '_custom_field_name', 1);
```

This will do the trick and remove all errors and notices.