# Add product attribute or custom field in woocommerce admin order page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When viewing an order in Woocommerce I need to get a specific attribute of the ordered items.
This attribute should be visible on the same row as the ordered item.

The attribute tends to change after a period of time so I would like to keep the same value of the attribute as it was when the customer ordered the item. Maybe this is done by sessions?

I would appreciate any help or example for this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find half the solution on the following page https://stackoverflow.com/a/25645735/4028658.

This lets me get the ordered items attributes but I still have the problem of keeping the same value of the attribute as it was when the customer ordered the item.